# Why setter function accepts the same datatype as that of its field in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to insert a string value to a private array in a typescript class using a setter function.
In my getter function, intellisense says that the value returned is a type mismatch as mentioned in the code below.

```
export class Player{
    constructor(private _skills:string[]){}

    get skills(){
        return this._skills  // Type string not assignable to type string[]
    }

    set skills(newSkill:string){
        this._skills = [...this._skills,newSkill]
    }
}
```

On removing the explicit function parameter type `newSkill:string` to just `newSkill`, the above error gets resolved as typescript expects an array of strings to be passed in the setter and not just a string.

We can insert a single string  by enclosing it in an array then merging the passed array with the private array field.

```
player.skills = ["single skill"]
```

```
export class Player{
    constructor(private _skills:string[]){}

    get skills(){
        return this._skills
    }

    set skills(newSkill){
        this._skills = [...this._skills,...newSkill]
    }
}
```

But why should we pass an array and not just a string to the setter function for situations where we need to insert just one skill value to the skills array at a time and not an array of skills?

Why **array of just one string** and not just string (as a datatype in the setter function) is the question?

Is it possible to avoid the string array datatype and set it to just a string datatype?

**Note:
The requirement is to insert/set one string value at a time and not array of values to the skills array using the set keyword of typescript**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the field. There's no intrinsic connection between `skills` and `_skills`. The requirement is that the return type of the getter must match the type of the parameter of the setter.

You *can* deal with it by using a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

```
export class Player {
    constructor(private _skills: string[]) {
    }

    get skills() {
        return this._skills;
    }

    set skills(newSkill: string[] | string) {
        if (typeof newSkill === "string") {
            this._skills.push(newSkill);
        } else {
            this._skills = newSkill.slice(); // Note: Completely replaces the value
        }
    }
}
```

...**but you shouldn't**, for a couple of reasons:

1. Every use of the getter has to check whether it got a string or a string array, even though it always returns an array.
2. Asymmetric APIs have been well proven to be hard to learn and hard to use (think `document.cookie`, *shudder*). (The API above is asymmetric in fact even though it isn't in definition, since the getter always returns an array.)

Instead, if you want the skills to be an array, make it an array, and have a method that lets you add a single skill or *add* an array of skills:

```
export class Player {
    constructor(private _skills: string[]) {
    }

    // Gets the array of skills -- you might want to make a
    // defensive copy, or return a frozen version or similar
    get skills() {
        return this._skills;
    }

    // Sets the array of skills, OVERWRITING previous ones
    set skills(newSkills: string[]) {
        this._skills = newSkills.slice();
    }

    // Adds one or more skills, which can be given as individual
    // strings or arrays of strings
    addSkills(...skills: (string|string[])[]) {
        // Add all the skills, which 
        this._skills.push(...skills.flat());
    }
}
```

*(Note: That uses the new [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method.)*

Comment: Thanks @T.J. for such an insightful answer

Comment: as u mentioned the setter param depends on the return type of the getter that in turn depends on the field type as it is expected from any getter function...a good conslusion to this situation would be to say that its unavoidable to pass only string datatype as a param to the ts setter rather its better to make  separate setter functions that would handle both as u mentioned. Agree?

Comment: @AdityaPatnaik - Yes, if you need to do anything "special" with what's given, I'd make that part a method rather than an accessor.

Comment: Thank you so much @T.J. , got to learn a lot from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got to know that the setter function always expects the field typed value to be passed into it.

In this case, skills is a string array. So the setter expects a string array as a parameter.

```js
player = new Player(["someskills"])
player.skills = [...somemoreskills] //has to be a string[] and not string
```

### Conclusion:

setter parameter datatype defaults to field datatype and it appears that its unavoidable to change it to accept **just a string** and **not accept array of strings**.
As a workaround to make a setter work with both string and string[], we could use pipe.

### Workaround: Accepts single string but also accepts an array of strings.

```
set skills(newSkill:string[]|string){
        if(typeof(newSkill)==='string'){
            this._skills = [...this._skills,newSkill]
        }else{
        this._skills = [...this._skills,...newSkill]
        }
    }
```

Suggestions with setting the setter param datatype  as a (`string` alone) would help!

Comment: *"Got to know that the setter function always expects the field typed value to be passed into it."* That's incorrect. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Making `foo.skills = ["x", "y"];` **add** skills rather than replacing them is a footgun.